# SolutionDir set to *Undefined* in post-build xcopy event

Tags: msbuild, xcopy

I have a project that has a post-build event that xcopies a DLLs to a certain directory:

```
xcopy "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).dll" "$(SolutionDir)..\UdpLocationService\bin\Plugins\" /d /y
xcopy "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb" "$(SolutionDir)..\UdpLocationService\bin\Plugins\" /d /y
```

However, I have CruiseControl.NET set up as a build server and MSBuild is failing on building that project due to this xcopy post-build event:

```
MSB3073: The command "xcopy "C:\Build\Services\Windows\VehicleServer\Plugins\Payload\bin\Debug\Payload.dll" "*Undefined*..\UdpLocationService\bin\Plugins\" /d /y xcopy "C:\Build\Services\Windows\VehicleServer\Plugins\Payload\bin\Debug\Payload.pdb" "*Undefined*..\UdpLocationService\bin\Plugins\" /d /y" exited with code 4. in Microsoft.Common.targets(3397, 13)
```

Any suggestions to get this fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- Unload your project file (e.g. *.csproj)
- Open your project file for editing
- Find the AfterBuild target
- Separate out the two invocations of XCopy into two distinct Exec tasks
- Save your changes and Reload your project file

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the first error but not the second:


MSB3073: The command "xcopy "C:\Build\Services\Windows\VehicleServer\Plugins\Payload\bin\Debug\Payload.pdb" "*Undefined*..\UdpLocationService\bin\Plugins\" /d /y" exited with code 4. in Microsoft.Common.targets(3397, 13)

Comment: I should also add that there is no AfterBuild or exec in the csproj file. This is what it looks like:

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>xcopy "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).dll" "$(SolutionDir)..\UdpLocationService\bin\Plugins\" /d /y</PostBuildEvent>
    <PostBuildEvent>xcopy "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb" "$(SolutionDir)..\UdpLocationService\bin\Plugins\" /d /y</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 31):

I just ran into the same problem with TeamCity.

The issue here is the $(SolutionDir) property in your build file. You haven't defined it in your call to MsBuild (this is why you see the word *undefined* in your output).

Call msbuild with the property set, like this:

```
msbuild myproject.csproj /property:SolutionDir="solution directory"\
```

Where "solution directory" is the directory containing your solution file. Note the trailing slash, you'll need that to make sure the path is correctly formed.

Comment: or you can include the trailing slash inside the double quotes - just remember to escape it with another backslash. So in my case, the call would be msbuild myproject.csproj /property:SolutionDir="%teamcity.build.checkoutdir%\\"

Answer (score 8):

I fixed this for problems with the Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact nuget package (which adds a similar post-build script), by adding:

```
<SolutionDir Condition="'$(SolutionDir)'=='' or '$(SolutionDir)'=='*Undefined*'">..\</SolutionDir>
```

right above the `<PostBuildEvent>`. You'll want to adjust the relative path to match your project layout.

Comment: This error can occur when building a project instead of a solution. When this happens, $(SolutionDir) is in fact *undefined* and the solution above gets around the limitation.