# How to copy automatically needed files from any dir to release- or debug-directory in Visual Studio 8

Tags: visual-studio-2008, directory, copy, xulrunner, geckofx

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and the imported GeckoFX-Framework in one of my projects. Since the Geckofx-13.0.dll uses the XUL-Runner itself, it's mandatory to have those files also in the build-directories of the project. Up to now I used to copy them manually into the two directories (Debug & Release).

I'm asking myself if I could tell VS to copy them automatically into those directories.

If those files are missing, the execution of the build fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the required files to your project, set them as "Content" in the properties window and set the Build Action to "Copy if Newer".

You could add a [Post-Build action](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3161232/736079) (right-click project, choose properties) to the release and debug configuration to copy the files to the output directory (you can use a macro instead of hard coding, that way the right destination is always used, also when it is edited in the project settings). A simple `copy .\Files\*.* $(TargetDir)` would probably work. Any command you can execute from the command line works here as well.

**The preferred way**:

You could add a [Post-Build target](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2010/02/18/build-extensibility-with-net-framework-4.aspx) (right-click project, unload project, rightclick unloaded project, edit project) and use the msbuild [`<copy>`](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx&ei=9y4aUaK3EYKd0QXRoICoBw&usg=AFQjCNEfzViBfzXA1KDM-7xAyBn34UVj5w&sig2=XnUuD2hdyyuGDQmVQVPnNA&bvm=bv.42261806,d.d2k) tasks to copy files from one location to another. You can again use a macro such as `$(OutDir)` or `$(TargetDir)` or `$(Platform)` and `$(Configuration)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did something like this:

```
XCOPY "$(ProjectDir)resources\libraries\xulrunner" "$(TargetDir)xulrunner" /E /I /Y /R
```

and it works perfecly. Now I have xulrunner in specified 'xulrunner' direcotry located in Debug/Release output directory so xulrunner files aren't mixed with app libs.
Remember to set new xulrunner directory in Xpcom.Initialize call.