# dotnet publish specific project with SolutionDir reference

Tags: .net, deployment, dotnet-publish

I'm trying to publish a specific project which is part of a solution. Many of the projects in the solution have settings which depend on the `$(SolutionDir)` value, but this is not available when the command line only points to the `.csproj` file instead of the `.sln`

Is there a way to inject a value to be used as `$(SolutionDir)` in this case?

Comment: the other projects are class lib or other projects?

Comment: @OpusCorpus class libs referenced by the project

Comment: If it is WinForms, then you would have a UI layer that should have reference to all other layers, and publishing it would do it.

Comment: I don't think it matters what kind of project it is, because it has pre- and post build events which depend on $(SolutionDir). Obviously you can have more than one solution which includes the same project, so when you publish the project individually there is no concept of "solution folder". It would be nice if we could set it manually to a specific location.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/9298864/5243037

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### short answer

yes it's possible with a property argument `-property:SolutionDir`

```
dotnet test Tests/Tests.csproj --logger trx --configuration Release -property:SolutionDir="C:\path_to_solution\"
```

note the `\` at the end of the path. Will save you some time :)

**note:** for the `azure devops` the argument line looks like (in my scenario)

`-property:SolutionDir=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/'`

### long answer

I have had problem when running tests from the CLI - azure devops would throw exceptions that files do not exist for the project.. No such exception is thrown when working from `VS2022`. The project basically has following config:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(SolutionDir)init.sql" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" LinkBase="\" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

so then if you just run the

```
dotnet test Tests/Tests.csproj --logger trx --configuration Release
```

error will pop-up

> Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file  'C:\path_to_solution\Tests\bin\Release\net7.0\init.sql'

see the solution in the short answer :)